# $u_t=u_{xx}+cu_x+au$, energy equation and spectrum for periodic boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> > For $a,c\in\mathbb{R}$ consider 
> >     $$
> > \begin{cases}u_t=u_{xx}+cu_x+au& \text{ on }x\in (-L,L)\\u(-L)=u(L), u_x(-L)=u_x(L) & \text{ periodic boundary conditions}\end{cases}
> > $$

(1) Determine the spectrum and the energy equation w.r.t. $L^2$-norm.

(2) How does the energy Dynamics relate to the spectrum?

Concerning the first question, I computed the spectrum to be
$$
\lambda=-\frac{\pi^2\ell^2}{L^2}+i\frac{\pi\ell}{L}c+a,~\ell\in\mathbb{Z},
$$

the rightmost Point on the real line is therefore $(a,0)$ and hence we should have instability.

For the energy equation, I get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\lVert u\rVert_2^2=-2\lVert u_x\rVert_2^2+2a\lVert u\rVert_2^2\leq 2a\lVert u\rVert_2^2
$$
and with Gronwall's inequality, it is said that we get
$$
\lVert u\rVert_2^2\leq e^{-2at}\lVert u_0\rVert_2^2
$$

(By the way: Why not $e^{2at}$ instead of $e^{-2at}$ since Gronwall says that $\lVert u\rVert_2^2\leq \lVert u_0\rVert_2^2\exp\left(2a\int_{t_0}^t\, dy \right)$ and here it seems to me that $t_0=0$?)

For (2) I do not have an answer but it seems to me that the exponential decay rate $-2at$ is connected with the fact that $a$ is the rightmost point in the spectrum?

Comment: It should be $e^{+2at}$ unless you mixed up the sign of the $a$ term in the PDE. The energy should not exponentially decrease unless $a<0$. Another thing to see this has to be wrong is to integrate the PDE over $[-L,L]$ which gives us $\int_{[-L,L]} u\,{\rm d}x = C e^{at}$ so unless $C=0$ the mean value of $u$ grows exponentially when $a>0$ which is incompatible with $\|u\|_2^2\to 0$.

Comment: Ok! Is it possible that for $t\leq 0$ we have the decay and that this is the relation with the spectrum: At least for $a>0$, we should have instability of the Zero solution and hence for $t\to -\infty$, we should have exponential decay? But for $t\to +\infty$ we should have exponential growth due to instability.

Comment: @Winther I am wondering whether the decay is meant with respect to $t\to -\infty$ and whether this is related to $a>0$ being the largest positive real part in the spectrum (i.e. instability of the zero solution and therefore solutions tend to the zero solution for $t\to -\infty$).

Comment: Who says this? Is this in your book? When people say "decay in time" then this is almost always as $t\to \infty$. The other way around would be a very strange use of language.

Comment: I was just thinking this might be right because this would fit the spectrum. For exponential growth with factor $2at$ I do not see how this is related to the spectrum. This is the only relation between the energy dynamics and the spectrum I can see.

Comment: What I think they might be asking for in 2) is the relationship between (linear) stability and the spectrum togeather with the relationship between stability and the evolution of energy. For linear PDEs some energy bounds implies stability which again is a statement about the spectrum ($\Re \lambda < 0$). I don't remember all the details here, so try to check your book on this for the exact theorems to reference.

Comment: Ah, you mean they just mean the fact that for $a<0$ we have (spectral) stability  as well as energetic stability since the norm is then bounded?